# $\mathbb{B} \backslash \lbrace U \rbrace$ is also a basis for usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Q: Let $\mathbb{B}$ is a basis for usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $U \in \mathbb{B}$ To show that $\mathbb{B} \backslash \lbrace U \rbrace$ is also a basis for usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$

My attempt : as $U$ is a basis element, it is an open set and for any point $x \in U$ we have some $V \in \mathbb{B}$ such that $x \in V_x \subset U$ and $U$ can be covered by union of $V_x$ for all $x \in U$. But I cant proceed further.

Answer (score 2):

You need to establish that the $V_x$ can be chosen different from $U$. In the usual topology of $\mathbb R$ this can be done by taking open balls (intervals) of arbitrarily small radius, e.g., if you started with $B(x,\epsilon)$ and this happened to be equal to $U$, just switch to $B(x,\epsilon/2).$

More explicitly, every $x$ is contained in an open ball that is small enough to be different from $U$. Since $\mathbb B$ was a basis, there is a $W_x\in\mathbb B$ that contains $x$ and that is itself contained in such a small open ball. But then $W_x$ cannot be equal to $U$ (being too small) so it must actually be an element of $\mathbb B\setminus \{U\}.$

Comment: Can you explain in a bit detail ? Thanks